# Update records in SQL table wothout specifying field names

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a functionality in T-SQL where it will go thorugh all my fields in a table, and anywhere it sees an record containing "none" it will update it to NULL. I don't want to pass in the name of the fields in my stor proc, as the number of fields in a table can vary.

So in other words it will be a loop that will go through my fields and will update it.

Comment: You'll need to find all non computed string columns from the metadata views such as `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` and then use dynamic SQL to update the relevant values.

Comment: Thanks, I will try all the solutions below.

Answer (score 1):

```
--Sample table with some test data.
CREATE TABLE guest.Test (
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    Col1 VARCHAR(16),
    Col2 VARCHAR(16),
    Col3 VARCHAR(16)
)

INSERT INTO guest.Test (Col1, Col2, Col3)
VALUES 
    ('other data', NULL, 'none'),
    (NULL, 'other data', NULL),
    (NULL, 'none', 'other data'),
    (NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('none', NULL, NULL),
    ('none', 'none', NULL),
    (NULL, 'none', NULL),
    (NULL, 'none', 'none'),
    (NULL, NULL, 'none'),
    ('none', NULL, 'none'),
    ('none', 'none', 'none')

SELECT * FROM guest.Test

DECLARE @Schema SYSNAME = 'guest'
DECLARE @Table SYSNAME = 'Test'
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @Tsql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'UPDATE [' + @Schema + '].[' + @Table + '] SET '

--Dynamically build a list of column names/values for the table, separated by commas.
SELECT @ColNames = @ColNames + '[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] = NULLIF(' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ', ''None''),'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
AND c.TABLE_NAME = @Table
--Filter by "String" type data types.  Did I leave any data types out?
AND c.DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR', 'CHAR', 'NVARCHAR', 'NCHAR')
--Keep the same column order, just for appearance.
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION 

--Remove last comma
SET @ColNames = LEFT(@ColNames, LEN(@ColNames) - 1)
SET @Tsql += @ColNames
SET @ColNames = ''

--Build a WHERE clause.  No need to unnecessarily update rows that don't need updating.
SELECT @ColNames = @ColNames + '[' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '] = ''none'' OR'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
AND c.TABLE_NAME = @Table
--Filter by "String" type data types.  Did I leave any data types out?
AND c.DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR', 'CHAR', 'NVARCHAR', 'NCHAR')
--Keep the same column order, just for appearance.
ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION 

--Remove last OR
SET @ColNames = LEFT(@ColNames, LEN(@ColNames) - 2)

SET @Tsql += ' WHERE ' + @ColNames

PRINT @TSql
--Uncomment when ready to proceed.
--EXEC (@TSql)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick sample of what Martin spoke of.  Here I'm selecting the top 5 columns from the schema, and then selecting records from those tables where the column='none'

I'm not executing, but rather just printing the resulting dynamic SQL for demonstration purposes.

If you want the secondary select to actually run, un-comment the EXEC(@SQL).

You can then modify this to UPDATE the column as needed, but as a warning, always PRINT before you EXEC, and read what it will do first!!!

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @COLUMN_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX), @TABLE_CATALOG NVARCHAR(MAX), @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX), @TABLE_SCHEMA NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE COL_LOOP CURSOR LOCAL
FOR
    SELECT TOP 5 TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_SCHEMA
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE IS_NULLABLE='YES'
    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('VARCHAR','NVARCHAR','CHAR','NCHAR') 
    --AND TABLE_NAME='tblXYZ'

    OPEN COL_LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM COL_LOOP INTO @TABLE_CATALOG, @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @TABLE_SCHEMA

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 5 T.[' + @COLUMN_NAME + ']
                    FROM [' + @TABLE_CATALOG + '].[' + @TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + @TABLE_NAME + '] T
                    WHERE T.[' + @COLUMN_NAME + '] = ''none'''
        PRINT @SQL
        --EXEC(@SQL)

        FETCH NEXT FROM COL_LOOP INTO @TABLE_CATALOG, @TABLE_NAME, @COLUMN_NAME, @TABLE_SCHEMA
    END
CLOSE COL_LOOP
DEALLOCATE COL_LOOP
```

The out put looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 T.[sAgentID]
                    FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[#0137E5BD] T
                    WHERE T.[sAgentID] = 'none'
SELECT TOP 5 T.[permission_path]
                    FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[#02F04FD2] T
                    WHERE T.[permission_path] = 'none'
SELECT TOP 5 T.[Form Name]
                    FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[7e1e7afb-a8cf-42e2-add6-688ee3245696] T
                    WHERE T.[Form Name] = 'none'
SELECT TOP 5 T.[Name]
                    FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[7e1e7afb-a8cf-42e2-add6-688ee3245696] T
                    WHERE T.[Name] = 'none'
SELECT TOP 5 T.[Score]
                    FROM [tempdb].[dbo].[7e1e7afb-a8cf-42e2-add6-688ee3245696] T
                    WHERE T.[Score] = 'none'
```

You can then copy this and run each select to validate accuracy before updating your code to do any work.

You may also wish to consider wrapping this whole thing in a transaction in case you need to roll it back.

Comment: PRINT, verify, then EXEC.  Excellent advice!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
DECLARE @update_stmt VARCHAR(8000)

SET @table_name = N'table_name'

SELECT @update_stmt = '
UPDATE ' + @table_name + ' 
SET ' + STUFF(CAST((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = CASE WHEN ' + 
                                 QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ''none'' THEN NULL ELSE ' + 
                                 QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' END'
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name 
                    AND DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR'
                    AND IS_NULLABLE = 'YES'
                    AND COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), COLUMN_NAME,'IsComputed') = 0
                    FOR XML PATH('')) AS VARCHAR(8000)), 1, 1, '')

PRINT @update_stmt
--EXEC (@update_stmt)
```